# Laravel use Illuminate\Http\Request; not working

Tags: php, laravel

namespace `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` not working for `Request::all();`

Comment: you want to get the posted parameters ?

Comment: @Rohit What is your method implementation and error message

Comment: FatalErrorException in AdminModel.php line 88:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::file()

Comment: if i am use Illuminate\Http\Request; then my post working and Request::all(); not working  i want to allowed both

Comment: which version you are using?

Comment: post your code here.we will get an idea then.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller {

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function store(Request $request) {
    $name = $request->all();
}}
```

Try with this it will work - its working fine for laravel 5.2

Answer (score 0):

You can can use dependencyy injection to get all input data like this:

```
<?php
...
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     use Illuminate\Http\Request;
     public function store(Request $request) {
           $data= $request->all();
           dd($data);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

`use Request;`

and check `Request` alias in **app.php**

```
'Request'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
```

Hope this work for you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in the following code.

```
<?php

namespace ...

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TestController extends Controller
{
  public function requestTest(Request $request) 
  {
     dd($request->all());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a little issue of name space, if you want to use Request::all() then please use name space like

use /Request;

Answer (score 0):

this issue is a namespace issue.
if you want to use Request::all() then you need to use use /Request namspace. or if you want to use Input::all() then you need to use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Answer (score 0):

We can use the request following way

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
public function FunctionName(Request $request)
{
    $request->all()
} 


use Request;
public function FunctionName()
{
    Request::all()
}
```